# Testing proxy with Indy

Tags: delphi, testing, proxy, delphi-xe2, indy

I extensively rely on Indy 10 to download/upload files (sent via https)

My code looks like this (I'm using **Delphi XE2**):

```
IdHTTP               := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

with IdHTTP do
begin
     HTTPOptions     := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv];
     AllowCookies    := True;
     HandleRedirects := True;
     ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

     IOHandler       := ASSL;
     Compressor      := ACompressor;
     CookieManager   := ACookieManager;

{$ifdef DebugProxy}
     ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
     ProxyParams.ProxyPort   := 8888;
{$else}
     if (TheProxyServer <> '') then
     begin
          with ProxyParams do
          begin
               ProxyServer   := TheProxyServer;    // DNS name of the proxy server or its IP address
               ProxyPort     := TheProxyPort;      // Port the HTTP the HTTP proxy listens on
               ProxyUsername := TheProxyUsername;  // Username if the proxy requires authentication
               ProxyPassword := TheProxyPassword;  // Password if the proxy requires authentication
          end;    // with
     end;
{$endif}
```

TheProxy*********** variables are all defined by the end user.

I need to make sure my application works across various proxy settings, but I know almost nothing about proxies :(

How can I do that? Is it enough to setup a proxy locally (or use something like Fiddler, or test against [proxy info defined in IE / WinInet](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0161.htm)), test locally to say I'm fine? Is there some kind of popular / defacto-standard proxy tool that companies / user use? (my application target both consumers & businesses)

**PS. This is a serious question!** Although I'm far from being a novice, I almost *never* had to deal with proxies (except maybe once to twice, very long time ago, enough to forgot everything about it)

Comment: Proxies are based on the standard. A HTTP1.1 compliant proxy must act as described in [rfc2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt).  A popular free proxy cache is [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), you can use it to test your software, but with INDY it usually is very easy since you just set properties and authentication info and INDY handles it internally.